# ng-model is undefined from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-controller

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/np7vf0t1/2/)

Hi,

Why the value from `foo()` function is undefined?

I found that the problem is if the model name is only `brand`but, it is not my problem. The name of my model is `car.brand`.

So my question is - how to access model from ctrl?

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-if="cars" ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <br>
    <label>{{car.name}}</label>
    <br>
    <label>brand</label>
    <select ng-model="car.brand" ng-options="car as car.name for car in brands" ng-change="loadBrands($index)">
      <option value="">select</option>
    </select>
    <label>model</label>
    <select ng-model="brand.model" ng-options="car as car.model for car in cars[$index].models">
      <option value="">select</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <button ng-click="foo()">
    save all
  </button>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$scope.foo = function() {
   alert("foo: " + $scope.car.brand);
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `ng-repeat`, you will have many cars, so your model you be filled in the cars:

```
$scope.foo = function() {
   for(var i in $scope.cars) {
     alert("foo: " + $scope.cars[i].brand);
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `car.brand as` or `car.model as`

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-if="cars" ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <br>
    <label>{{car.name}}</label>
    <br>
    <label>brand</label>
    <select ng-model="car.brand" ng-options="car.brand as car.name for car in brands" ng-change="loadBrands($index)">
      <option value="">select</option>
    </select>
    <label>model</label>
    <select ng-model="brand.model" ng-options="car.model as car.model for car in cars[$index].models">
      <option value="">select</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <button ng-click="foo()">
    save all
  </button>
</div>
```

or do

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-if="cars" ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <br>
    <label>{{car.name}}</label>
    <br>
    <label>brand</label>
    <select ng-model="car" ng-options="car as car.name for car in brands" ng-change="loadBrands($index)">
      <option value="">select</option>
    </select>
    <label>model</label>
    <select ng-model="brand" ng-options="car.brand as car.model for car in cars[$index].models">
      <option value="">select</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <button ng-click="foo()">
    save all
  </button>
</div>
```

whatever is before the `as` is the value the `ng-model` will get